# Bootstraps navbar-collapse not working on iPhone

Tags: iphone, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, navbar

I just started this project, so it is pretty bare, but I've already run into a problem. When I resize my desktop browser to mobile size in both Safari and Chrome, everything works exactly as it is supposed to. However, when I view it on an iPhone 5 or iPhone 6 (and I'm assuming other mobile devices), the dropdown menu button does nothing. I am using Safari on these devices. You can see a live version of my code here: http://fkrtestsite.byethost3.com/ .

I have already looked through many similar questions, but no solutions have worked for me. I already have the meta tag, my data-target matches the id of the button, I believe I have all of the necessary plugins. I'm totally new to bootstrap, so hopefully this is just some noob error with the way I have everything ordered. I hope somebody can help me out!!

Below I have attached my html and css.

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

.logo-img {
 min-width: 70px;
 max-width: 190px;
 height: 100%;
 width: auto;
}
.header-icon {
 font-size: 50px;
}
.navbar-collapse {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
 background-color: #DED0E5;
}
.navbar-nav {
 display: inline-block;
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
}
.nav-options {
 padding: 10px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
 color: white;  /*Sets the text hover color on navbar*/
 background: #A163C2;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
 color: white; /*BACKGROUND color for active*/
 background-color: #4E0065;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
 color: #262626;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #66CCFF;  /*change color of links in drop down here*/
}
.nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus {
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: silver; /*Change rollover cell color here*/
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
 color: black; /*Change active text color here*/
}
.navbar-header {
 background-color: #C9A7DB;
}

@media (min-width: 767px) {
.navbar-nav {
 margin-top: 30px;
 width: auto;
}
.nav-options {
 padding: 5px;
 font-size: 2vw;
}
.navbar-collapse {
 background-color: #C9A7DB;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>My Site</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/fkr.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class = "navbar navbar-default" role = "navigation">
    <div class="row">
      <div class = "navbar-header">
        <div class = "navbar-toggle" 
                 data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#navbarcollapse"> 
                 <span class="header-icon glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="pull-left"><img src="../logo.png" alt=""></a>
       </div>
      <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "navbarcollapse">
        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
          <li class = "nav-options"><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
          <li class = "nav-options"><a href = "#">Adopt</a></li>
          <li class = "nav-options"><a href = "#">Get Involved</a></li>
          <li class = "nav-options"><a href = "#">Store</a></li>
          <li class = "nav-options"><a href = "#">About</a></li>
          <li class = "nav-options"><a href = "#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --> 
<script src="../js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script> 

<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed --> 
<script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a look at the site and it seems to work fine on my Nexus 6. So I believe it may be an issue with Safari.

You do seem to have some errors on the page that may be causing issues with Safari.

Follow this link to find and fix them: https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffkrtestsite.byethost3.com%2Findex.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0